# how to handle onclick = getRedirectPage(34342,55,46) using Jsoup?

Tags: button, onclick, jsoup, screen-scraping

I am doing a school project that need to use jsoup to scrape some datas from certain website.
I saw a button as following attribute:

```
<a rel="nofollow" 
onclick="getRedirectPage(37443499,2206,801)" 
class="showtime_btn btn btn-default seat_3" 
id="37443499" 
href="javascript:void(0)" role="button">06:40PM
<br> 
<small>IMAX 3D</small
></a>
```

//below is the getRedirect method. I was trying to understand it,
but I dont know what language they using, have no idea where to learn the necessary knowledge to understand it, please help me out.
thank you !!

```
var timeout = "";

function clickRedirect(){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Redirect_CTA', 'click', viewModel.popupRedirectAdsEventName());
}

function getRedirectPage(shid, movieid, cinemaid){
    $('#page-overlay').show();

    ga('send', 'event', 'Movie_SelectShowtime', 'click_showtime', movieid, cinemaid);

    $.get("https://www.popcorn.app/sg/showtime/redirect",
    {
        showtimeid: shid
    },
    function (data){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#page-overlay').fadeOut();
        },100);

        var dt = JSON.parse(data);
        if(dt.status > 0){
            dt = dt.data;
            viewModel.popupRedirectToLang(dt.lang_redirectto.replace('%s', dt.site));
            viewModel.popupDisclaimer(dt.lang_disclaimer);
            if(dt.redirect_ads != undefined && dt.redirect_ads.event_name != undefined){
                viewModel.isExternalTraffic(true);
                viewModel.popupRedirectAdsUrl(dt.redirect_ads.url);
                viewModel.popupRedirectAdsLabel(dt.redirect_ads.label);
                viewModel.popupRedirectAdsEventName(dt.redirect_ads.event_name);
            }else{
                viewModel.isExternalTraffic(false);
            }
            viewModel.popupRedirectNote(dt.lang_redirectnote);
            viewModel.popupFollowUrl(dt.follow);
            viewModel.popupLangBtn(dt.lang_btn_txt);
            viewModel.targetBlank("_blank");

            //campaign:
            if(dt.campaigns != undefined && dt.campaigns.trackingUrl != undefined){
                viewModel.isCampaignValid(true);
                viewModel.adImage(dt.campaigns.adImage);
                viewModel.campaignName(dt.campaigns.campaignName);
                viewModel.isSmallerFont(dt.campaigns.isSmallerFont);
                viewModel.campaignPercentage(dt.campaigns.campaignPercentage);
                viewModel.companyName(dt.campaigns.companyName);
                viewModel.campaignAddress(dt.campaigns.campaignAddress);
                viewModel.campaignTrackingUrl(dt.campaigns.trackingUrl);
                viewModel.discountedPrice(dt.campaigns.discountedPrice);
                viewModel.originalPrice(dt.campaigns.originalPrice);
            }else{
                viewModel.isCampaignValid(false);
            }

            $("#redirectPopupTarget").show();

            $(".close_btn").click(function(){
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                $("#redirectPopupTarget").hide();
            }); 

            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = dt.follow;
            },5000);
        }
    })
    .error(function (er) {
        console.log("Error:", er.responseText);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#redirectPopupTarget").css('height', $(window).height());


});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzeeZ.png)

below link is the id = redirectPopupTarget

Comment: This button executes javascript method `getRedirectPage` with some arguments. You have to examinate in source of your webpage what does this function do. Jsoup will be no help, since this library does not execute javascript code.

Comment: thanks for replying, is there a tool for such dynamic redirect?

Comment: You have to check what does this scirpt do in source of your webpage. Without the context it is hard to help.

Comment: hi， i has updated the detail, what is the language they are using? I trying to understand it ,but it seems to complicated for me .

Comment: This is javascript with jQuery. This code does some other things, but I think you are most interested in getting redirect link. This is done by sending request to `https://www.popcorn.app/sg/showtime/redirect?showtimeid=shid`. Where shid is first parameter of you javascript function (https://www.popcorn.app/sg/showtime/redirect?showtimeid=37443499). The response to this request is in form of JSON, and element you are looking for is in the field `follow`.

Comment: wow thanks！！！ thank you so much !!

Comment: I getting "follow" inside JSON, its redirect to booking page, but it is still inside their website instead of official website?

Comment: okay, thanks, it only with specify one cinema..problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

This is javascript with jQuery. This code does some other things, but I think you are most interested in getting redirect link.

This is done by sending request to https://www.popcorn.app/sg/showtime/redirect?showtimeid=shid. Where shid is first parameter of you javascript function (https://www.popcorn.app/sg/showtime/redirect?showtimeid=37443499).

The response to this request is in form of JSON and element you are looking for is in the field follow